# Great quality video and audio with ffmpeg2theora?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, codecs, free-software

Xenial Xerus has a decent version of `ffmpeg2theora`:

```
andrew@athens:~$ ffmpeg2theora | head -n 6
ffmpeg2theora 0.29

    Xiph.Org libtheora 1.1 20090822 (Thusnelda)
    Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.5
    FFmpeg   libavcodec 56.60.100
    FFmpeg   libavformat 56.40.101
andrew@athens:~$
```

But the command options for this application are still a little difficult, particularly when you move *beyond* these basic video and audio settings:

```
-v, --videoquality     [0 to 10] encoding quality for video (default: 6)
                               use higher values for better quality
-V, --videobitrate     encoding bitrate for video (kb/s)

-a, --audioquality     [-2 to 10] encoding quality for audio (default: 1)
                                use higher values for better quality
-A, --audiobitrate     [32 to 500] encoding bitrate for audio (kb/s)
```

What is a command line to produce great, free video clips that takes advantage of *all* of the `ffmpeg2theora` command line possibilities?

**Note:**

To escape the possibility of this question being deemed: 'Too Broad' or 'Opinion Based' I have placed a sample file here for testing:

```
wget http://www.andrews-corner.org/samples/matrix_sparring_h10.mkv
```

Command lines *based on this input file* would be very welcome...